# Package immer - Prototype Pollution

Tags: reactjs, npm

I faced recently a high vulnerability when I installed LINQ into react. The problem occurred with immer package. I read that they already fixed the problem in version 8.0.1 but I could not solve it by just updating the package. I will be grateful for any suggestion
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJr5y.jpg)

Comment: I faced same issue with react-scripts-> react-dev-utils ->  immer. And resolved by running npm audit fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue with react-scripts-> react-dev-utils-> immer. My issue resolved after running `npm audit fix`.